# Make objects change color during collision?

Tags: materials, keyframes, color, collision

**Hello there,**

I'm using blender to create an animation with 150 objects. These objects each have an individual material with a simple Emission node, in which it's base color (RGB) has been individually keyframed and animated to produce color patterns and effects between all 150 objects.

**Check exemple here:**

[image: Color animation exemple]

This was achieved by individually keyframing certain colors onto 1 object, then copying those keyframes and pasting them onto the other 150 objects in specific timings to create the final color pattern animation I desired.

As I'm still quite new to Blender, I was hoping to learn and understand if there is a more effective way of achieving these results. I've seen that perhaps I could set-up a Constraint or Modifier that would make the 150 objects change color based on colision with other objects.

**As an example of what I'm trying to explain, I will attach these gifs below:**

[image]

***(Object colliding with spheres)***

[image]

***(Same prespective, but the object is hidden. Spheres change color during collision with said object)***

[image]

***(Final result: notice the colors changing)***

**Note:** these gifs are just a representation of what I intend to achieve - the colors were changed manually.

Do you think this can be done with Blender (or any addons)? If so, I would appreciate any help!

Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: This is more than possible in Blender, with a choice of _much_ simpler and more flexible processes than the one you illustrate. Can you give us some background?  Are you fixed to working with imported geometry, (just doing the colouring in Blender)? Or could you envisage generating the geometry in Blender, too?

Comment: Hello Robin, appreciate your reply.

I was hoping that would be the case, as manually animating the colors for 150 or more objects can be quite time-consuming.

As of now, I'm generating the geometry, animating the objects' locations and then coloring them all in Blender.

To give some background, this blender animation will be used for a drone light show - so each sphere object represents 1 drone. I have an addon that will generate and export a file containing the XYZ coordinates and RGB values for each individual sphere at every x milliseconds.

Comment: Great stuff. All in Blender makes it simpler still. Will post when I can.. you'll be attracting other answers, too, I would hope. They might cover it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep an eye out for replies. :)

Comment: Hello @RobinBetts

Unfortunately I haven't gotten any further replies on this topic. I've looked for similar threads and tutorials on Youtube, but I couldn't find a solution that suits my exact necessities. I was wondering if you could share some of your knowledge (when possible - of course) or point me in the right direction as what to look for.

Again, I truly appreciate your support.

Comment: That's ok! I'm grateful for the positivity in this community and your willingness to help others learn more about this "craft". Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand your question, but the addon I use exports the XYZ coordinates and RGB values for each drone (at every x millisecond) in a file to be read by another application.

As long as the object has RGB values during the animation, I think it is okay.

Here is an example of a single line exported by the addon:
X: 0 Y: -442 Z: 337 RC: 204 GC: 204 BC: 204

Comment: I'm guessing that wouldn't work if the colors were just assigned at render-time, by a shader.. that the colors would have to be stored on the objects, (vertex-colors?) for the exporter to be able to get at them... which would be fair enough, just a slightly different method. Basically.. what does your exporter expect?

Comment: Oh yes, that is exactly it. The colors would need to be stored on the objects so that the addon can correctly export their values. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you - that is perfectly ok! I appreciate your support and will keep checking for updates to this thread.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I've tried to make up for being late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is tricky to answer briefly, because you have so many options open to you. All these examples are Geometry Node groups, working on animated mesh-objects comprising vertices without faces or edges. All the GN groups store colours on the mesh, in an Color Attribute layer, on vertices. Your exporter should be able to pick up the locations of the vertices, and the colours stored on them.

In order to be able to *see* the effects, a simple supplementary GN group is added at the bottom of the modifier stack, instancing an icosphere on each vertex, with an associated shader:

[image]

I imagine the exporter would work on the meshes with this GN group silenced.

#### Interactions with external meshes

Your example shows a test for inside/outside an external mesh, switching colours accordingly. This can be achieved by firing a ray from your vertices, and testing to see whether the hit face is backfacing to the ray:

[image]

This example allows you to set ray direction and length, inside & outside colors..

[image]

... or you could vary the color of your points according to their proximity to an external mesh:

[image]

effects analogous to this:

[image]

Or, for perspectival effects, you could treat your points as a projection-plane. Here an eye-point is set up behind the points, and rays are fired from there, through the points, at the target object. The color of the points reflects whether or not the target is hit:

[image]

.. for results like this:

[image]

#### Or, just work with textures

Sometimes, there may be no need for external objects, and you could just work with textures. They can be 3D, calculated from the positions of the points in the point-object's space, or 2D, projected through the point-object, or perhaps based on some UV-mapping of the points. The same techniques apply here as would in any shader-tree.

[image]

Here, an animated mix is made between 'Bands' and 'Spherical' *Wave* textures, through the points, while the points themselves are animated. The possibilities here are as wide as with any other procedural texturing.. (endless). Or, with suitable resolution in your points, you could compose your own image-textures or movies in any application to project through the points.

[image]

[image]

If you need any *particular* effect, it would probably be worth posting a question specific to it.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the well constructed and thorough reply, lots of interesting stuff to play with! I'll definitely work on this in the next few days and will post a reply here or on the forums if I run into any questions with these methods you presented. Again, I really appreciate the time you put into this.

Comment: @JohnnyR. Thanks! No problem. By all means comment here if something in this answer is unclear. If it's substantially a new question, create a new Q post for it. (I don't know how familiar you are with the workings of SE sites.. don't post commentary as new answers :) )

Comment: Hello! I've recently posted another question regarding this topic and I thought maybe you could have some feedback. I'll link the question below: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278189/make-objects-take-the-color-assigned-to-the-vertex-they-are-currently-tracking