# Make objects take the color assigned to the vertex they are currently tracking?

Tags: geometry-nodes, constraints, vertex-groups

I have a grid of 300 individual mesh objects (spheres) and each move by constantly tracking 300 vertices through the Copy Location constraint. The vertex grid comprising of zero edges and faces was generated using Geometry Nodes.

Would it be possible for the Spheres to "extract" or "copy" the color of each vertex they are currently tracking?

For instance - as perfectly exemplified by a member on another topic - this would be the end result I intend to achieve: it

[image]

[image]

The difference is that I'm working on 300 different objects and not on a Geometry Node group that instances an icosphere on each vertex, with an associated shader.

I've attached a simple .blend with a short animation displaying movement and color control:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I haven't got back to you.. been busy.. There are probably quite a few approaches to this, depending on your workflow,  why these are separate objects, and when they are made into separate objects. Can you describe why you can't use instances of one object?

Comment: Hey Robert - sorry for the late reply as well. I'm using an addon that helps create and animate drone shows on Blender, but this addon works with multiple objects (spheres) instead of an object comprising of multiple verts. These spheres are animated by tracking the positions certain vertices over time, defined by me.

I could create the instances myself but the addon helps tracking speeds, safety distances, and overall simplifies the workflow of native Blender tools. If the objects / drones could take the color of the vertex they are attached to, I could work with procedural "light effects"

Comment: Hey @RobinBetts , don't mean to bother you as I know life can get busy - just a reminder that I've attached a .blend file you can look at whenever you have time. :)

Comment: Don't know  how this slipped through my net. Sorry. So.. you want to copy a colour from  a mesh, to objects bound to single-vertex groups of its vertices, with a copy location coinstraint. How do you want the colour to be stored in the objects? Is this for visualisation only, or does the colour need to be exported in some form? At first sight, this is not an obvious system.. I'm imagining you have your reasons for doing it this way, and merely displaying colours through shaders won't do?

Comment: That is correct, basically I want to change the color of a primary mesh, and then the objects bound to the vertices of that mesh to copy its color and store them on their Material BDSF. That way their color data could be exported.

Comment: All the objects would have the same material, with different base colour, or different materials? Can you give an idea of the export format? There may be an easier way.

Comment: All the objects would have different materials. Of course - the export consists of a .csv file for each sphere object (named, for example, Drone_01, Drone_02 ... and so forth). I'll attach an image here: https://i.ibb.co/QDzFKh8/csvs-2.png

Comment: At first sight, it seems unnecessary to me, to create separate objects and materials? All the points (or vertices, if the base really has to be a connected mesh) have indices, which can be mapped to file names, if necessary. All the points have a location and colour attribute (or vertex colour), which can be looked up and spat out. All can be associated with a frame-number, I'm pretty sure.. having said that, I'm not exactly a script-meister. But I do think this Q may be able to  be rephrased, looking for direct, scripted output. Avoiding complication.

Comment: The information you have provided so far has been very helpful in guiding me to the correct direction - for that I'm very grateful. I also have limited knowledge in scripting and I would just like to mention I've been using the tool ChatGPT to help me successfully create some useful .py scripts. Might be useful for you as well! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Johnny! It amazes me that ChatGPT / VS Copilot work at all :) Best combination, IMO:   Python - knowledge, and at least a good sketch of the API. Then use those tools to take the slog out of the empty page, a starting-point for improvement / optimization.

Comment: if you can send a file of your exact situation, it would be easier to come up with a solution that will work for you.
some solutions might work on the file you attached that won't work in your specific situation. (you said there is a grid without faces, yet the file you sent has a grid with faces)